# Regex help - find certain substring and not the other

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex that find whether there is a comma in a string, but not slash-comma. For example - there is a match here: **aaa,aaa**
There isn't a match here: **aaa\,aaa**

Can you think of a solution?

Answer (score 2):

This should work: `[^\\],`. It should match any character which is not a `\` followed by a `,`. (I tested this using Regex Pal's [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/)). In your case, depending on what language you are using, you might just need to use this: `[^\],`.

This pattern however assumes that `,` is **not** the first letter in the string. If you also want to cater for such an eventuality you should consider using this: `(^,)|([^\\],)`. This will check that the `,` is either the first letter of the string or it is not preceded by a `\`.

EDIT: The problem seems to be that for a case like so: `aaa,aaa`, the regex I propose takes one of the characters (the one before the `,`). I have tried the following line in Java code: `String[] grp = "aaa,aaa".split("(?<!\\\\),");` and it worked for me (as proposed in other answers above). If you provide information on what language you are using you might have a greater chance for getting help.

Comment: Hi, I tried to split a string based on your regex doing this:
    String [] set = "aaa,aaa".split("[^\\\\],")
The result was ["aa","aaa"].
How can we change the regex to split the string into ["aaa","aaa"]?
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @user1520863: I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) to match only the comma:

```
/(?<!\\),/
```

If your regex engine does not support that, you'd use a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), which also matches the character before the comma (or the string start):

```
/(^|[^\\]),/
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to split a string based on your regex doing this: String [] set = s.split("/(?<!\\\\),/"); but there was no split... How can we change the regex to split the string into ["aaa","aaa"]? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

try this one :

```
.*(?<!\\),.*
```

There are four differenet assertions of the type in general:

```
(?=pattern)
    is a positive look-ahead assertion
(?!pattern)
    is a negative look-ahead assertion
(?<=pattern)
    is a positive look-behind assertion
(?<!pattern)
    is a negative look-behind assertion
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to split a string based on your regex doing this:
   String [] set = s.split(".*(?<!\\\\),.*,");
but there was no split...
How can we change the regex to split the string into ["aaa","aaa"]?
Thanks for your reply!